# What does the bool? return type mean?

Tags: c#, .net

I saw a method return `bool?`, does anyone know the meaning of it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`T?` is a C# syntax shortcut to `Nullable<T>`. So `bool?` maps to [`Nullable<bool>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx). So in your case it's a struct that either is `null`, or has a `bool` value.

If a `Nullable<T>` is `null` that's a bit different from a reference type being null. It basically is a struct containing the underlying type and a boolean flag `HasValue`. But both the runtime and the C# language have a bit of magic to pretend that a `Nullable` with `HasValue==false` is really null. But the difference still leaks sometimes.

The underlying type is implicitly convertible to the nullable type (`bool`->`bool?`). To get the underlying type from the nullable type, you can either cast explicitly (`(bool)myNullableBool` or use the `Value` property (`myNullableBool.Value`). You should check for `null` before though, or you'll get an exception if the nullable value is `null`.

- [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx)
- [`Nullable<bool>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

Answer (score 13):

In C#, the "primitive" types can't hold a null value:

```
int blah = null;
```

That will make an exception because 'int' can't hold a null value.

Same with double, float, bool, DateTime...

That is fine really. The problem comes when you are using databases. In a database you can have rows that can be null, like Age (that is an int).

How do you hold that row on an object? Your int cannot hold the null value and the row can have null.

For that reason MS created a new struct, the Nullable, you can pass to that struct a "primitive" type (or a struct) to make it nullable like:

```
Nullable<int> blah = null;
```

That will not make an exception, now, that variable can hold an int and a null.

Because Nullable is too long, MS created some kind of alias: If you put the '?' after the type, it becomes nullable:

```
int? blah = null;
Nullable<int> blah = null;
```

This two lines are EXACTLY the same but the first one is easier to read.

Something like that :)

Comment: It's a struct, not a class. And it accepts other structs as parameters, not only primitive types.

Comment: It's only to explain it a little bit, not fully detailled, but you're right, I will change it :)

Answer (score 5):

Any (no-nonsense<sup>1</sup>) **value type** suffixed with `?` makes it a nullable type:

- `int?` is a nullable integer
- `bool?` is nullable boolean which makes is actually a **triple state boolean** (`true`, `false` and `null`) - think of it when you need to implement some triple state behaviour.
- ...

In other words `object` type doesn't support nullable definition as `object?` because it's reference type and can have a value of `null` already.

### Real-life usage

Nullable types are most often used against database, because they make it really easy to transform nullable int/bit/datetime/etc. columns to CLR types. Like in this example:

```
create table Test
(
    Id int identity not null primary key,
    Days int null,
    ExactDate datetime null,
    Selected bit null
)
```

This can easily be translated to POCO:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Days { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ExactDate { get; set; }
    public bool? Selected { get; set; }
}
```

> <sup>1</sup> **no-nonsense** refers to all value types except `Nullable<T>` which is a value type per se, but it wouldn't make any sense in making it nullable once more... Avoid such stupidity... It won't compile anyway because `Nullable<Nullable<int>> i = null;` can be interpreted in two ways:
>
> > • `i.HasValue == false`
> >     • `i.HasValue == true && i.Value.HasValue == false`

Comment: @Robert Any **value type** that has a default constructor. Nullable<Nullable<int>> isn't valid. :-)

Comment: @xanatos: You're right. Who would be so daft to even think of writing `int??`? ;)

Comment: You might want write `T?` and then supply a nullable as T. There are occationally situations where it'd be useful.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Any real-life example where it could be actually useful?

Comment: @Robert I was wrong. All Value Types have default constructor. Simply the Resharper showed me "his" version of the definition of Nullable. Reflector has one without the new() constraint. Nullable<Nullable<T>> is illegal because it's illegal :-)

Comment: @xanatos: Yes I'd expect something like that to be explicitly checked by the compiler. How would you interpret an assignment `x = null`? Should it be: `x.HasValue == true` and `x.Value.HasValue == false` or should it be `x.HasValue = false`?

Comment: @Robert The "real" HasValue would be saved only on the "outher" Nullable. When HasValue = true, both the "outer" and the "inner" Value would be set (and the inner HasValue would be set to true). The "outer" nullable would mask the "inner" one totally. It would be usefull only as a generic parameter. You receive T and you want to internally use T? without checking if T is already nullable.

Comment: @Robert But I see that you can't pass int? to a generic class "where T : struct"... It's a funny world, the world of nullable types. Full of strange magic. :-)

Comment: There's no real-life use of 'bool?', because everyone knows that a tristate bool is defined as {True, False, FileNotFound} ;-).