# C# What is the '?' operator

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the bool? return type mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064806/what-does-the-bool-return-type-mean)

I came a cross the following property in a class

```
public long? EmployeeId { get; set; }
```

I googled this operator with no luck, according to the MSDN [MSDN  OPERATOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) there is only the operators `??`  null-coalescing operator and `?:` conditional operator. 
but what about `?`

Comment: That is a `long` that can be null

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this case `?` is not an operator. It is a shorter way to write: `Nullable<long>`

`T?` is exactly the same as `Nullable<T>` (with `T` a type)

It is called a nullable type (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

It is used to allow "non-nullable" type (like `int`, `long`, a `struct`) to be assigned a `null` value.

It is useful when you need a possible invalid state for a value type, or if the data is being retrieved from a database that may contain a null value.

Answer (score 6):

This is not an operator. This is a shorthand for the [Nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

It's a nullable type. Look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

> The syntax T? is shorthand for System.Nullable, where T is a value
>   type. The two forms are interchangeable.

Source:
[Look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It makes the type nullable, which is needed to assign null to structs.